# ASP.NET Menu: how to build custom menu

Tags: asp.net, treeview, menu, repeater, multi-level

i have this situation: i have to build a menu with datasource from the db, because i have to filter them among the user that is loged in. i have tried building a menu using repeater, and all this works fine till i realized that i wanted the menu with more than two levels. i have also tried with treeview, but i really don't want this solution (problem with the style and the treeview doesn't have a pretty view).

**Could anyone give me just the idea ?**

thnx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are securing your pages in the conventional sense (ie--using ASP.NET's builtin permissions system), you can just use the normal SiteMapProviders as they will security trim menus for you.

If you need to do custom, try making a class that implements [IHeirarchicalDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ihierarchicaldatasource.aspx) and then bind anything appropriate (eg--ASP.BulletedList) to that.